# Chat search is returning no results

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, search

Searching any Stack Exchange chatroom doesn't seem to work at the moment.

For example, the word "this" certainly appears in The Nineteenth Byte but

https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=this&room=240

results in `0 messages found` for me.

Even with the user specified there are no results:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=hello&user=118010&room=1

Yet user 118010 (FOX 9000) literally [just said hello in the Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29856321#29856321).

[I'm not the only one having this problem.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29875273#29875273)

Comment: We're aware and it's currently being investigated.

Comment: Yeah, it happens once in a while, think it's at least the third time in the last year or so.

Comment: Now it only produces results from before 2014

Comment: [tag:status-incomplete]

Comment: Current results are from 2015 and earlier - 11pm EST

Comment: There's probably a lot more chat indexing to do than they realised. Give it a little longer and it should index all fine :)

Comment: @Quill actually it's stuck in April 2015. Most likely something broke.

Comment: Marked complete, but still doesn't work for any searches, for certain chat rooms.  I can search for some words, in all rooms, but even something like "the" comes up with 0 results in all rooms.  (The search in the OP for "this" still doesn't work, either)

Comment: @Khale_Kitha The [devs are aware and are working on it](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/735509019813654533).

Comment: @bluefeet It's still rather misleading that this is marked as complete when it's not.

Comment: @bluefeet Are you sure this is all fixed? "[this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=this&user=&room=240)" still gives 0 results and "[egg](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=egg&user=&room=240)" is wonky and inconsistent

Answer (score 8):

I don't know *where* the analyzer config went for that specific index, but it was missing. We're rebuilding the chat-stackexchange index, which will take some time to complete (probably under an hour or so?). Once that's done, searches should be fine again.

Comment: Found the analyzer config, it's just in front of you! http://i.stack.imgur.com/ienkt.jpg :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nah, that's the kool-aid.

Comment: It's been about 2 hours and chat search is still not fully working :/

Comment: @Adam maybe better put the [tag:status-completed] tag only after the index rebuild is complete? After all, the rebuild might fail, or take  long hours during which the bug isn't 100% fixed just yet.

Comment: Still no results past April 2015, 16 hours later.

Comment: Hmm. That sounds like a new/different issue. I'm out today, but I'll ping someone to take a look.

Comment: Nick says it should be all good now.

Comment: @AdamLear Are you sure this is all fixed? "[this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=this&user=&room=240)" still gives 0 results and "[egg](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=egg&user=&room=240)" is wonky and inconsistent

Comment: @HelkaHomba It *was* fixed. Possible that something's broken again, though. It's been almost a year since this answer.